# Why is PHP's type hinting allowing NULL in place of an object?

Tags: php, magento, types

Why is PHP's type hinting allowing an object through when it is NULL? Here's the code.

```
public function addBodySegments(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
{
    if ($order === null) {
        echo 'fail';
    }
}
```

I have *not* provided an "$order = null" default value in the function signature, so my understanding is that PHP should be guaranteeing me that I have an instance of an object in $order.

Could the author of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` have written that class in such a way as it somehow passes the type hint, or is there a more general PHP thing going on here that I don't know about?

Comment: Does `$order == null` fix it?

Comment: @Pikamander2 the problem appears to be that an exception should have been thrown before it gets to that statement.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I had multiple sections in my code that called addBodySegments(), and one of them called it without any arguments. Surprisingly, PHP's type hinting is bypassed when you call the the method without providing any arguments at all.

Curious design choice.

Comment: This isn't true. PHP will throw an exception: `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to function() must be of the type $type, none given ...`

Comment: Something else is at play here. If you call `myFunction()` it should not execute `myFunction($some_argument)`  That is not the same function

Comment: @HPierce is correct - I was sure this was wrong, but have confirmed it just now by replicating the above code.